# Read file as list, edit and write back

Tags: list, python-2.7, text-files

Say I have a textfile containing the following:
*1:Programming:Adam:0

2:Math:Max:0
3:Engineering:James:0*

I am trying to read this textfile as a list, then have a user specify which 0 of a line they want to change to 1, then rewrite the changes made back into textfile. 
So for example if a user specifies line 2, I want the 0 in line 2 to be changed to 1 and then save the changes made back onto the textfile.

So far I have the following and I just can't get it to over write it:

```
class Book_list:
    def __init__(self,book_ID,book_title,book_author,availability):
        self.book_ID = book_ID
        self.book_title = book_title
        self.book_author = book_author
        self.availability = availability

    def __str__(self):
        return ('ID: ' + self.book_ID + '\nBook_Title: ' + self.book_title +
                '\nBook_author: ' + self.book_author +
                '\navailability: ' + self.availability + '\n')

    def __getitem__(self,book_ID):
        return self.book_ID
    def __getitem__(self,availability):
        return self.availability

x=str(raw_input('enter line number.'))

with open('database.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
library = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    data = line.split(':')
    b = Book_list(data[0],data[1],data[2],str(data[3]))
    library.append(b)

for i in range (0,len(library)):
    if (library[i])[0]==x and (library[i])[3]==0:
        (library[i])[3]== '1'

with open('database.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines( library )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read file and store it in a string. then using split make a list from file:

```
str='a:b:c'
lst=str.split(':') #lst=['a','b','c']
```

edit as you like and then join them with .join:

```
str2=':'.join(lst) #str2='a:b:c'
```